# Mocking document.createRange for jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

Jest, through JSDom I imagine, does not have `document.createRange` defined. How can I overwrite or provide this behavior?

The version we wrote for our custom JSDom + mocha setup (ran before all tests) looks like this:

```
global.Range = function Range() {};

const createContextualFragment = (html) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div.children[0]; // so hokey it's not even funny
};

Range.prototype.createContextualFragment = (html) => createContextualFragment(html);

// HACK: Polyfil that allows codemirror to render in a JSDOM env.
global.window.document.createRange = function createRange() {
  return {
    setEnd: () => {},
    setStart: () => {},
    getBoundingClientRect: () => {
      return { right: 0 };
    },
    getClientRects: () => [],
    createContextualFragment,
  };
};
```

Is there a way to provide this to jest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a script that sets up the polyfill you want -- let's call it "mockument.js" for this example. Within the jest configuration of your `package.json` set `setupFiles` to point to this script:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["raf/polyfill", "./scripts/mockument"]
}
```

As shown above, you can also use module names (e.g. `raf/polyfill`).

One *sweet* thing about this is that you can create your own module for common initial setups for testing and use them across several component libraries that need the functionality.

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["@nteract/mockument"]
},
```

Comment: Also helpful polyfill here from enzyme https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1626#issuecomment-398588616

Answer (score 9):

I added the polyfill in `setupTests.js` as described in this [thread](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/478).

```
if (window.document) {
    window.document.createRange = () => ({
        setStart: () => {},
        setEnd: () => {},
        commonAncestorContainer: {
            nodeName: 'BODY',
            ownerDocument: document,
        },
    });
}
```

For it to work with TypeScript I had to add `// @ts-ignore` above `commonAncestorContainer`.